# What Azure region is best for Provider Hosted Apps in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app, azure

Is there any way to determine what Azure region would perform the best for Provider Hosted Apps in SharePoint Online?

I normally select "Eastern-US" but I have no way of knowing where exactly the SharePoint bits are hosted for a given tenant.

How can I make sure I'm getting the least latency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an idea about where your Office 365 data is stored at [Microsoft Online Services - Where is my data?](https://www.microsoft.com/online/legal/v2/?docid=25)

According to that your data is probably in the region closest to where the admin stated the company resided.

If you're using CSOM (Client Side Object Model) from server code then you should probably place your App in the same region.

But if your users are somewhere else and you're mainly using CSOM in JavaScript in the browser or you're serving large amount of data stored in the App and not in SharePoint then you should place your App in the region closest to the users.

Answer (score 3):

The best region would be whatever is closest to you. As far as I know, these are the general locations of the Azure data centers:

```
North Central US – Chicago
South Central US – San Antonio
West US – California
East US – Virginia
```

So if you are rolling a provider hosted app in Azure, you'd want to tie your Azure servers to the region that is closest to you.